# I am developing an application with Office JS I try generate base64 with workbook is possible?

Tags: excel, office-js, office-addins, excel-addins, excel-web-addins

I am developing an application with Office JS I try generate base64 with workbook is possible?

generate base64 with workbook

Comment: Do you need to get a base64 representation of the workbook or just paste a base64 image?

Answer (score 0):

There isn't yet an Office JS API to get the Base64 representation of the workbook. If your file is stored on SharePoint or OneDrive for Business, you can use the Microsoft Graph API to retrieve the Base64 representation.

If you have a specific scenario in mind and using Microsoft Graph is not an option, please consider logging your request in the [Microsoft 365 Developer Community](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/microsoft-365-developer-platform/idb-p/Microsoft365DeveloperPlatform).